# Is it possible make vendor angular component ignore html font-size css setting?

Tags: css, angular

I use the vendor time picker component. Unfortunately, it uses rem units for most of its sizes, but pixels for positioning clock elements.
So when I'm trying to improve my application on mobile using font-size decreasing for small screen sizes:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  html {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
}
```

the widget becomes unusable due to selection elements shift from the other ones.
I can use

```
":host >>> ... "
```

angular css hacks to customize the widget's style but manual recalculation and repositioning of 24 clock elements is not a simple task (if it is event possible).

Is it possible to force the widget to ignore html font-size setting?

Comment: Seems the unit approach is really bad, but you can try view Encapsulation techniques for that. Simply add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to your `@Component` decorator

Comment: @AzkarMoulana This doesn't work. ViewEncapsulation.None just removes the possibility to make ":host >>> ... " style changes while ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom option removes style completely from everything.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a badly designed widget. Basically if they mixed `rem` units with `px` you cannot do anything to fix that. You could switch to using `em` units yourself and change only the app font-size, but it has other implications too, of course.

So either it is you forking the widget or you using a global style overriding the widget. Instead of recalculating the px sizes you could as well replace the rem units with different measure.